# Pandas Data Frame from Web is not Displaying Correctly Compared to the Native CSV File

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plotly

I am trying to make a program that analyzes stocks, and right now I wrote a simple python script to plot moving averages. Extracting the CSV file from the native path works fine, but when I get it from the web, it doesn't work. Keeps displaying an error: 'list' object has no attribute 'Date'

It worked fine with .CSV, but the web thing is messed up.
If I run print(df), it displays the table really weirdly.

```
import pandas as pd 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_html("https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL/history?period1=1428469200&period2=1554699600&interval=1d&filter=history&frequency=1d")
x = df.Date
y = df.Close

a = df['Close'].rolling(50, min_periods=50).mean()
b = df['Close'].rolling(200, min_periods=200).mean()

plt.plot(x, y)
plt.plot(a)
plt.plot(b)
plt.savefig("AAPL Stuff")
```

I ran in Jupyter Notebook.

I expected the output out[1] an image of the chart, but I got the error:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-18-d97fbde31cef> in <module>
      4 
      5 df = pd.read_html("https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL/history?period1=1428469200&period2=1554699600&interval=1d&filter=history&frequency=1d")
----> 6 x = df.Date
      7 y = df.Close
      8 

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'Date'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data got placed in a (one-element) list.

If you do this, after the `read_html` call, it should work:

```
df = df[0]
```

Comment: Hey, sorry for the late response, I had to work on another project. I get this error now: ```KeyError: 0```, what does this mean? Sorry for the ignorance, I am new to python, I work in CAD mostly. Thx

Answer (score -1):

Did you mean to access the Date feature from the DataFrame object?
If that is the case, then change:

`python x = df.Date` to `python x = df['Date']`

`python y = df.Close` to `python y = df['Close']`

EDIT:

Also: `python df.plot(x='Date', y='Close', style='o')` works instead of plt.plot

Comment: When I tried:  ```python x = df.Date``` to ```python x = df['Date']```

```python y = df.Close``` to ```python y = df['Close']``` I got the error: ```TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str```